# Computing expectations of an array, suggestions for speed improvements

Tags: arrays, performance, numpy

I have a (N0, N1, N2, N3) Matrix V and a (N1, N1) Matrix M. N1 is typically around 30-50, N0xN1xN2xN3 is around 1 000 000. I want a new Matrix EV, for which the i0, i1, i2, i3 entry is given by

```
np.sum(V[i0, :, i2, i3] * M[i1, :])
```

My current code to achieve that is:

```
  V_exp = np.tile(V[:, :, :, :, None], (1, 1, 1, 1, N1))
  M_exp = np.tile(M.T[None, :, None, None, :], (N0, 1, N2, N3, 1))
  EV = np.sum(V_exp * M_exp, axis = 1)
  EV = np.rollaxis(EV, 3, 1)
```

I have to perform this operation many times, and it is the absolute bottleneck of my code. I wonder if there's any potential for a speed improvement of my code. I appriciate suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single call to [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) would perform all those operations in one go, after extending `V` to a `5D` shape with [`np.newaxis/None`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis), like so -

```
EV  = np.einsum('ijklm,mj->imkl',V[...,None],M)
```

Thus, we are avoiding any intermediate arrays for a memory efficient solution.

**Explanation**

(1) Starting code that involved extending dimensions :

```
V_exp = np.tile(V[:, :, :, :, None], (1, 1, 1, 1, N1))
M_exp = np.tile(M.T[None, :, None, None, :], (N0, 1, N2, N3, 1))
output1 = V_exp * M_exp
```

In `np.einsum`'s way, it would be translated as :

```
np.einsum('ijklm,mj->ijklm',V[...,None],M)
```

Please notice that we have used `mj` instead of the usual `jm` for `M` to correspond to `M.T[None, :, None, None, :]`.

(2) Next up, we have :

```
EV = np.sum(V_exp * M_exp, axis = 1)
```

Thus, we are summing along `axis = 1`, so the einsum call would need the *output string specifier* be changed from `->ijklm` to `->iklm`.

(3) Finally :

```
EV = np.rollaxis(EV, 3, 1)
```

For this porting of `rollaxis`, we just need to *push up* `axis=3` to `axis=1`'s position and *push down* each of `axes=1,2` one position to the right. Thus, the *output string specifier* would change from `->iklm` to `->imkl` to give us :

```
np.einsum('ijklm,mj->imkl',V[...,None],M)
```

Comment: This is awesome, almost 10 times faster! Thank you!

Comment: @TobiasR Very nice! Glad to help.