# Efficient computation of conditional expectation of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I have a `(N0, N1, N2, N3)` Matrix `V`and a `(N1, N1)` Matrix `M`. `N1` is typically around 30-50, `N0xN1xN2xN3` is around 1,000,000. I want a new Matrix `EV`, for which the `i0, i1, i2, i3` entry is given by:

```
sum(V(i0, :, i2, i3) * M(i1, :)', 2)
```

I need to do this operation many many times and my main concern is speed.

I asked for a solution to the same question using numpy a while ago ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401011/computing-expectations-of-an-array-suggestions-for-speed-improvements)) It was suggested there I use `np.einsum`, which worked fantastically. I now need to port the whole thing to Matlab and I was wondering what the most efficient solution would be in that case.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the `np.einsum` is the Einstein summation on all operands, there are toolboxes out there that does exactly that: http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16275-tprod-arbitary-tensor-products-between-n-d-arrays If you need a custom made one you can attemp to write one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. To clarify, I am not necessarily looking for a function that allows me to use einstein notation, but a fast implementation of the matrix operation I want to perform. Judging by the comments on Mathworks I am not sure TPROD is what I want.

Comment: I want a new Matrix EV, for which the i0, i1, i2, i3 entry is given by sum(V(i0, :, i2, i3) * M(i1, :)', 2). Matrix Multiplication would give me something entirely different.

Comment: I see, so in the loop form you are doing `sum((V(1:i) .* M(i+1,:))',2)` for each `i`? that can be parallelized using something like bsxfun or arrayfun. Can I also confirm that the * is a element-wise multiply or a cross multiply?

Comment: Are you sure about your formula? For now `V(i0, :, i2, i3) * M(i1, :)'` should output a scalar and there'd be no need to take the sum

Comment: And by the way, `V(i0, :, i2, i3) * M(i1, :)'` outputs the same result as `sum(V(i0, :, i2, i3). * M(i1, :), 2)` (note the absence of transpose and the elementwise multiplication)

Comment: If you clarify that point, there will be an answer involving reshaping and 2D matrix multiplications which should be pretty fast